# What's the best way to concurrently udp broadcast for beacon on LAN, while accepting multiple tcp clients in select.select server in python?

Tags: python, sockets, concurrency

Below code results in error:

OSError: [WinError 10048] Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted

I'm not stuck on multiprocessing lib; considered subprocess popen. Or would threading be best? Once the UDP portion is going, no further communication with it is necessary (other than graceful shutdown)

```
# 2 processes: main server, and udp broadcast

from multiprocessing import Process
#import multiprocessing as mp
import os
import socket, select
import time

port = 8999
tcpSocket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
tcpSocket.bind(('', port))
tcpSocket.listen(5)
inputs = [tcpSocket]
outputs = [tcpSocket]

def udpbcast():
    server = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM, socket.IPPROTO_UDP)

    # Enable broadcasting mode
    server.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_BROADCAST, 1)

    message = b"A&Av.01"

    while True:
        server.sendto(message, ('<broadcast>', 37020))
        print("Sent: ", message)
        time.sleep(5)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    #info('main line')
    p = Process(target=udpbcast, args=())
    # For some reason, starting the udp broadcast process is interferring with the tcp socket stuff
    p.start()
    # Need a way to exit loop cleanly
    while inputs:
        print('Server processing loop...')
        infds, outfds, errfds = select.select(inputs, outputs, inputs, 5)
        if len(infds) != 0:
            for fds in infds:
                if fds is socket:
                    clientsock, clientaddr = fds.accept()
                    inputs.append(clientsock)
                    print ('connect from:', clientaddr)
                else:
                    data = fds.recv(1024)
                    if not data:
                        inputs.remove(fds)
                    else:
                        print("Data: ", data)
        if len(outfds) != 0:
            for fds in outfds:
                fds.send("Python select server!\n")
        #time.sleep(5)
    p.join()
```

Comment: Threading in Python is convenient because only one thread runs at a time (the Global Interpreter Lock) and therefore you often don't need to worry about using locks. To do it single-threadedly, you could choose to set the timeout to be the time before the next broadcast, and if it times out, do the broadcast.

Comment: The error 10048 means another program on your computer is already bound to the address you tried to bind to.

Comment: The error is misleading in this context. If I comment out the line that starts the udp process, the select.select server code works (or at least appears to do so).

Comment: Probably because both processes try to bind to the same port